# Is there is a way to manage and deploy changes on different environments?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-delivery

I would like to setup a few different environments for BigQuery database (dev, test, prod)
I am wondering how to manage them, deploy new changes (from dev to test to prod) , configuring CI/CD. As I understand I should create 3 projects with its own Google BigQuery.

Maybe there is something familiar with Microsoft Azure SQL DacPac (Visual Studio SDT) + Azure DevOps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should read [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations) with best practices for enterprise organization.

Google Cloud provides a range of services to help you adopt DevOps practices. Features include integrated source [code repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories) and [continuous-delivery tooling](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery). For more details, see Google Cloud's [DevOps solutions](https://cloud.google.com/devops).

Tool in GCP, which is equivalent to Azure DevOps is [Cloud Code](https://cloud.google.com/code), it helps you write, deploy, and debug cloud-native applications quickly and easily. Extensions to IDEs such as Visual Studio Code and IntelliJ are provided

Typical project ID naming convention might use the following pattern:

```
[company tag]-[group tag]-[system name]-[environment (dev, test, uat, stage, prod)]
```

I hope it helps.